# Cannot access 'useState' before initialization in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In react.js I am adding a form with some parameter.

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
```

`AddUser` component has some parameter in which I have to store data.

```
const AddUser = () => {
    const [user, useState] = useState({
        name: " ",
        username: " ",
        email: " ",
        phone: " ",
        website: " "
    });
```

This code is used for initializing the parameter of `useState`.

```
    const {name,username,email,phone,website} = user;

    const onInputChange = e => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <div className="w-75 mx-auto shadow p-5">
                <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Add User</h2>
```

This is the form where I submit some data of parameters.

```
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" value={name} name="name" onChange={e => onInputChange(e)} class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" value={username} name="username" onChange={e => onInputChange(e)} class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="email" value={email} name="email" onChange={e => onInputChange(e)} class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" value={phone} name="phone" onChange={e => onInputChange(e)} class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" value={website} name="website" onChange={e => onInputChange(e)} class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Website" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddUser;
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useState' before initialization
    at AddUser (AddUser.js:4:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

Comment: Your post doesn't contain any question. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is a react hook, you cannot use its name to name a variable or function. Change your `AddUser` code shown on this page to this:

```
const AddUser = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: " ",
        username: " ",
        email: " ",
        phone: " ",
        website: " "
    });
```